# Creating a timer to call a method in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application

I am develop a Console Application which is able to read and write data from an Arduino through serial port. When I read from the Arduino I have to wait to get a response from it so creating a timer is the better option.

So I've created this Timer and will run every 2000 milliseconds.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.Odd, 7, StopBits.One);

    Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);

    port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;

    port.Open();
}

private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
{
    //Call the method
}
```

What I want to do is call this method into the `TimerCallback`

```
private static void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

        // Leitura de dados
        string incoming = port.ReadExisting();
        string questionmark = "?";
        string carriageReturn = "\r";
        string text = string.Empty;

        switch (incoming)
        {
            case "@r\r":
                // send the message back
                port.Write(questionmark + "*" + carriageReturn);
                break;
            case "@{/r":
                port.Write("@" + text);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown command sent by the Arduino!\n Command: " + incoming);
                break;
        }
    }
```

How should I call the Port_DataReceived method?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a timer.  The `DataReceived` event should be fired whenever the data arrives in the serial port (I assume you are using the `SerialPort` class.  Can you show how you are wiring up the event?

Comment: Already updated the post @ChrisDunaway

Comment: This code seems to have  a problem in that the Main method will exit immediately after opening the serial port.  Once Main exits, the program will end.  How are you keeping the program alive to receive events?

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange that you would want to call the event handler directly from your code?

Suggest having a new function that is called from your timer and also from the event handler.

But why you want to do this still seems smelly to me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the timer. Remove it.

The event will be called whenever data is received on the serial port. You don't need to call it yourself.

Comment: So I keep `private static void TimerCallback(Object o)` empty?

Comment: You can even remove the timer and the timer method unless you need it later, but I doubt you will need it - at least not for serial communication.